# I can't seem to figure out these error with SplashScreen and StatusBar Ionic 6.12.4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnzcH.png)

I'm building an app using Ionic 6.12.4 for some reason I just keep getting this error code. I'm placing a screenshot of the error and a sample of my code. If there is something I can do without or add please let me know.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'List',
      url: '/list',
      icon: 'list'
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Check your `app.module.ts` you might have Imported them without ngx.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `SplashScreen.hide();` directly.

This is what the error message tries to tell you. `SplashScreen` is already the value you try to instantiate in your constructor.

The value is an instance of `SplashScreenPlugin`.